# Attaching file in data node of a list instance?

Tags: feature

I have a custom list definition and a custom list instance in a feature.

If I want to populate some data in the list at its creation, I can use the [data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458199.aspx) node.

How can I add an attachment to this item ?

I've tried to use a module

```
<Module Name="CustAttachment" Url="Lists/MyList/Attachments/1">
    <File Path="MyFile.doc" Url="MyFile.doc" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
</Module>
```

But it does not works. It says "cannot create folder Lists/MyList/Attachments".

I know I can do this in code, but is there a xml-way of attaching a file in a custom list instance ?

thx